# ios - how to cause a delay in the middle of a method

Tags: objective-c, ios, timer, delay

I'm working on a card game and trying to get cards to deal one after the other.  I have a method that animated a card from the deck to a player, and in viewDidLoad I call this method four times.  The problem is all four cards get dealt simultaneously.  How do I stop a method in its tracks for a period of time?

I know that the scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval method calls another method after a delay, but I'm looking for a way to interrupt the current method after calling the deal method once and then continuing with the rest of the current method.  sleep() also doesn't work.  I tried putting it between calls to the deal method, but it just executed all the sleep()s and then did all the animation at once again.  Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: have you tried - (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay ?

Answer (score 3):

You are going down the wrong road. Attempting to sleep a method is not the way to approach this. You want to break the task into steps to be performed serially and perform each step only after the previous step is completed.

Say you have a variable called 'cardCounter' and one called 'cardMax'. Then you have a method called 'dealCard'. In `viewDidAppear` you intialize 'cardCounter` to zero and 'cardMax' to 4 (or however many cards are to be dealt. Then you call the 'dealCard' method.

(actually, you probably want a method called `newGame` or something since you will likely want to have multiple games and you don't want to tie your game setup to the `viewDidAppear` event. So in `viewDidAppear` you would call 'newGame' and do your initialization there.)

```
- (void)dealCard {

  cardCounter++;

  if (cardCounter > cardMax){
   // all cards are dealt
   // call some method to start game
   // or do any other set up;

  } else {

   // call some method to animate the card
   // using core animation with a completion handler?
   // using a ^block with a completion handler?

   // either way, in the completion handler call
   // 'dealCard' again
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A hint. Create a setup method which is called from your init only once! In that setup method you can work with `performSelector" as tomi said. The Selector is "your" method that moves a card from the deck to the player.

```
(void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay
```